# Is there a way to warm up a Firebase cloud function before it is called so it is faster?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am aware that I can set the minimum number of instances for a cloud function.
However, I have some functions that are called infrequently so this is not practical from a cost standpoint.

I do know beforehand when a user is going to call a cloud function from the UI as it is the next step in a series of steps.
Is there a way to warm the function up before the actual call so it is faster or is it the only way to actually call it?

If the only way is to call it then I could make the function so that it can be called with a warmUp parameter which just starts and then exits the function 5-10 seconds before it is called by the user. Could this approach work?

Comment: Just call the function asynchronously. That will cold start an instance if one is not ready.

Comment: @JohnHanley yeah that is what I was thinking. I would call it when the user arrived on the page but that would be say 5-20s before they clicked the "next" button that called the function. I can't predict the exact length of time.

Comment: The function will still be warm 30 seconds later. I am not sure of the exact time limit as Google does not publish a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @John Hanley mentioned you can call the function asynchronously. That will cold start an instance. You can checkout the recommendations mentioned in [Document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) to optimize your deployed function which will reduce the cold start time. Please checkout the  video [minimize cold start time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM) for details.

You can refer to the document for another workaround [Cold start workaround](https://siriwatknp.medium.com/cold-start-workaround-in-firebase-cloud-functions-8e9db1426bd3).

To avoid the cold start you may want to consider running your own server instances using something like App Engine to have [warm up requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests).

Comment: Thanks some good resources. I had already watched that video but was not aware of the other links. Here is another good video with actually measurable performance increases if anyone is interested https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY.